# Opensearch: Data node costs

Tags: opensearch

I don't understand the costs of having 1 data node vs having 2 or more data nodes.

Will I have the same cost regardless of the number of nodes?

If I have 2 data nodes, that means that I will have double the cost of the instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the instance size: `i3.2xlarge` would be ~2x more expensive than `i3.xlarge`.

If you use one instance size then yes, 2 nodes would be 2x more expensive than 1 node but you'll get more resilience (if one node goes down your cluster can still get updates and serve data) and rolling restarts.

Though, Opensearch requires an odd number of nodes for master election to work reliably so 3 smaller nodes might be better than 2 larger ones.